# Bootstrap + Chosen Multiple Select Dropdown Always Open

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to have "Standard Select" and "Multiple Select" from http://alxlit.github.io/bootstrap-chosen/ to be always open instead of acting like dropdown ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually add the open css class to the container when after you initiate the plugin in your code:

```
$(".chosen-container").addClass("chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active")
```

also you need to edit the close function in the source code to stop the css class from being removed inside the plugin file:

```
line 696: this.container.removeClass("chosen-container-active");
line 793: this.container.removeClass("chosen-with-drop");
```

It sure does not look the cleanest or easiest solution, but it's quick, looking at the source code will give you extra insight on how it works and how you can edit it to meet your requirements

Comment: the plugin file: chosen.jquery.js, and no worries, it is my bad I didn't specify

Comment: ok it worked but I still need to click on ones the page loads. the first line "chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" did not work for me :)

Comment: where did you put it? it has to be right after you iniate the plugin on your select item

Comment: It kind of worked, but still a bit wrong. See screenshots; It does this > http://i.imgur.com/Wu5TF2s.png  instead of doing this > http://i.imgur.com/SNatfNm.png

Comment: do this instead of addClass: $(".chosen-container").trigger("mousedown.chosen");
example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dY43w/